# Correctly compute square root digital expansions

Tags: python, square-root

[Project Euler's problem number 80](https://projecteuler.net/problem=80) reads:

> It is well known that if the square root of a natural number is not an
>   integer, then it is irrational. The decimal expansion of such square
>   roots is infinite without any repeating pattern at all.
>
> The square root of two is `1.41421356237309504880...`, and the digital
>   sum of the first one hundred decimal digits is `475`.
>
> For the first one hundred natural numbers, find the total of the
>   digital sums of the first one hundred decimal digits for all the
>   irrational square roots.

This is the code that I have produced for this question:

```
from decimal import *

from math import sqrt

getcontext().prec = 100


def digitalsum(n):
    sum = 0
    for a in n:
        sum += int(a)
    return sum
total = 0
for a in range(1, 101):
    if not sqrt(a) % 1 == 0:
        ans = str(Decimal(a).sqrt())
        ans = ans[2::]
        print(a)
        print(digitalsum(ans))
        print("-------")

        total += digitalsum(ans)
print(total)
```

It is showing up the wrong answer, and I presume I have missed something along the way. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The problem does **not** say to ignore the integer part of the numbers.
- By specifying a precision of 100 decimal digits simply means that 100 digits will be used during the computations **not** that you'll get the first 100 exact decimal digits. Simply increase the precision to ensure the computations yield at least 100 correct digits:

  ```
  getcontext().prec = 102
  ```

  <sup>Using `101` is not enough to get the correct answer.</sup>
- Also, you'll have to correctly obtain the decimal digits:

  ```
  ans = str(Decimal(a).sqrt()).replace('.', '')[:100]
  ```
- Lastly the first 100 natural numbers go from `0` to `99` inclusive **not** from `1` to `100` inclusive.

So your code would become:

```
from decimal import *

from math import sqrt

getcontext().prec = 102


def digitalsum(n):
    sum = 0
    for a in n:
        sum += int(a)
    return sum

total = 0

for a in range(100):
    if not sqrt(a) % 1 == 0:
        ans = str(Decimal(a).sqrt()).replace('.', '')[:100]
        print(a)
        print(digitalsum(ans))
        print("-------")
```

this yields the correct answer.

The code can be greatly improved and shortened:

```
from __future__ import print_function    #for python2 compatibility.

from math import sqrt
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext


getcontext().prec = 102

total = 0
for a in range(100):
    if not sqrt(a) % 1 == 0:
        ans = str(Decimal(a).sqrt()).replace('.', '')[:100]
        digits = map(int, ans)
        print(a, sum(digits), "--------", sep='\n')

        total += sum(digits)
print(total)
```

Comment: Why is `getcontext().prec = 101` not enough?

Comment: @abaldwin99 Try it and you'll see it returns an incorrect answer. It is **not** true that to obtain `x` exact digits you simply need to use `x+1` digits during computations, independently of how many computations you do and which operations take place. In this case using `102` makes thing work. I started using `120` and then looked for the smallest number that gave the correct answer.

Comment: @abaldwin99 Because `sqrt(5)` equals `2.23...4970..." rounded to 101 digits it becomes `2.23...50`, but rounded to 102 digits it becomes `2.23...497` - the difference makes the 100th digit different.